# How regroup all rescues of begin block and switch type of error later?

Tags: exception, ruby-on-rails-4, typeerror, rescue

for this moment I have a block like

```
  begin
    yield
  rescue MyError => e
    call_specific_method
    call_method_foo
    render json: { error: e.to_s }
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    call_specific_method
    call_method_foo
    render json: { error: e.to_s }
  rescue => e
    call_specific_method
    call_method_foo
    render json: { error: e.to_s }
  end
```

so I have lot of duplicate instructions because they are similar for each exception :

```
call_method_foo
render json: { error: e.to_s }
```

but I have specific instructions too :

```
call_specific_method
```

I need to do something like :

```
  begin
    yield
  rescue => e
    if e.type == ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
       call_specific_method
    elsif e.type == MyError
       call_specific_method
    else
      call_specific_method
    end
    call_method_foo
    render json: { error: e.to_s }
  end
```

**So how can I test type of exception in single rescue ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the exception class like this:

```
rescue => e
  if e.is_a?(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    ...
  end
end
```

In any case, I'd better extract the common code to an external private method:

```
def foo
  ...
  begin
    yield
  rescue MyError => e
    call_specific_method
    render_error_for(e)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    call_specific_method
    render_error_for(e)
  rescue => e
    call_specific_method
    render_error_for(e)
  end
end

def render_error_for(e)
  call_method_foo
  render json: { error: e.to_s }
end
```

Comment: why it's better extract common code and not specific code?

Comment: I assumed that every ``call_specific_method`` is different for every exception class, isn't it?

Comment: yes, ok, in fact the rescue list, is same like my if, so it's ok, thx.

Comment: I just test, but only one rescue `rescue => e`, don't catch all exceptions errors...

Comment: Which one is not catching? Which code are you using?

Comment: I found, for catch all in one rescue, just use top of Exception hierarchy with : `rescue Exception => e` instead of `rescue => e`